# Why is x printing the size of string?

Tags: c, printf

I am relatively new to C.

Was solving a question and was hit with this line of code.

So why is x printing the size of the string?
How exactly does printf work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    x = printf("stackoverflow");
    printf("Value of x:%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
13
```

Comment: Read carefully the documentation of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: According to man page of `printf()`: `Upon  successful  return,  these functions return the number of characters printed`.

Comment: On *nix or OS X, you can open a terminal window and type `man 3 printf` to get the documentation for `printf`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For each question you should also tell us what you expected instead of the real result.

Comment: I was expecting a true(1) or false(0) value to be stored in x. Depending if the print statement successfully executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return type of printf is *int* and it returns the number of characters it printed. So in your case it is returning **length of the string**.